# How can I make this stored procedure (SQL Server) easier to read?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, temp-tables, code-readability

Below is the pseudo code of my current stored procedure. First, I have a HUGE query that creates a temp table. Then, I have other queries inside the stored procedure that are querying that temp table.

My goal is to make my stored procedure more readable. The HUGE query is making it difficult because it takes up so much space. I have tried creating a separate stored procedure for this huge query to create a temp table, but the temp table cannot be accessed outside of that other stored procedure.

Does anyone know of a more readable way of writing this code? If my question doesn't makes sense, then I'll rephrase it. Thanks.

```
Alter Procedure spMyStoredProc
Begin
    --Value of 1 for each param means I want to execute the query
    @sqlQueryA Bit = 0,
    @sqlQueryB Bit = 0,
    @sqlQueryC Bit = 0

    Select Columns
    Into #MyTempTable
    From **HUGE Query**

    If @sqlQueryA = 1 
    Begin    
        Select * From #MyTempTable
    End
    Else If @sqlQueryB = 1
       ... 
    Else If @sqlQueryC = 1
    Begin
        Query something else from #MyTempTable
    End
    Else
        Return
End
```

Below is a side issue that Evaldas Buinauskas and I were discussing on this thread:
  I'm adding the code below that contains an inline table valued function. My HUGE query has several local variables. Below is the pseudocode. The code resulted in an error.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_myFunction()
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    --Declaration is not allowed
    Declare @myLocalVar As DateTime
    Set @myLocalVar = '2019-01-10'

    #HUGE Query
    Where SomeColumn = @myLocalVar
)
```

Comment: Question:  What is the issue with making it readable?  Use spacing/comments to make it cleaner.  You can seperate out the larger query into its own SP and use a permenant table outside temp db and name it StagingSomething, but unless your using it elsewhere why that makes it more complicated.

Comment: Not really a more readable way but the performance of this is going to be terrible sometimes and totally fine other times. You need to consider reworking this a bit. https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/09/15/multiple-execution-paths/

Comment: I'm not a fan, but have you looked in to Insert-Exec https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/05/27/sql-server-how-to-insert-data-from-stored-procedure-to-table-2-different-methods/

Comment: readability isn't as important as performance, would you agree? I wouldn't put a huge query to encompass multiple possibilities into a temp table just to determine what to select from it. Instead, I would create a paramertize that query, and nest it in a proc if need be.

Comment: Smaller font? But seriously, making the huge query a view would move it out of your stored procedure. Some people don't like this kind of approach but I see no issue

Comment: We were thinking about inserting the HUGE query into a permanent table. I wanted to see if I could find a way to create a temp table for learning purposes and to prevent creating too many of these tables in the database. I also thought about creating one big sp, but the added queries were joining several other tables. I wanted to make my code readable, so either me or someone else in the future can decipher the code. The HUGE query is only returning 8,000 records currently, but I'd like to make sure it's performing well. I added my solution with Insert-Exec below. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: The people mentioning performance were definitely right. I used the Insert-Exec way. I didn't realize how bad the performance would be. Some of my queries on the temp table worked fine, but the ones that used the Like keyword were unusable. This was good for my learning. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Make your huge query a view

```
Select *
Into #MyTempTable
From MyView
```

Also, since it appears your query is mutually exclusive you don't need three bits.

Pass a single value, a string or an enumerated value to check which query to run, then short circuit by returning.

```
IF @Query = 'QueryA'
BEGIN
 Select QueryA From #MyTempTable
RETURN 1;
END;

IF @Query = 'QueryB'
BEGIN
 Select QueryB From #MyTempTable
RETURN 1;
END;

--throw an error if the query is not found
```

Comment: This will solve most people's issue. In my original question, I didn't mention my HUGE query had several local variables.  Local variables are not allowed in Views. Thanks, this helped me learn more about Views!

Comment: I also made the change you recommended. Instead of having several parameters as Bit types, I created one variable and passed a string to it. Each string represented the a query off of the temp table.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned this:

> My goal is to make my stored procedure more readable. The HUGE query is making it difficult because it takes up so much space. I have tried creating a separate stored procedure for this huge query to create a temp table, but the temp table cannot be accessed outside of that other stored procedure.

Depending whether your query has parameters or not, I would probably wrap that query into a view or inline table-valued function to isolate it.

So your stored procedure then literally becomes as short as what you have now:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spMyStoredProc
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Value of 1 for each param means I want to execute the query
    @sqlQueryA BIT = 0,
    @sqlQueryB BIT = 0,
    @sqlQueryC BIT = 0,

    SELECT Columns
    INTO #MyTempTable
    FROM dbo.ViewOrInlineValuedFunction

    IF @sqlQueryA = 1
    BEGIN
        SELECT *
        FROM #MyTempTable
    END;
    ELSE IF @sqlQueryB = 1
    BEGIN
        SELECT *
        FROM #MyTempTable;
    END;
    ELSE IF @sqlQueryC = 1
    BEGIN
        SELECT *
        FROM #MyTempTable
    END;
END;
```

Couldn't you modify function to accept parameters? :)

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_myFunction(@myLocalVar DATE)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
    SELECT *
    FROM HugeQuery
    WHERE SomeColumn = @myLocalVar
);
```

Then function call can be called as simple as:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.fn_myFunction('2019-01-10');
```

Comment: Since, my HUGE query has local variables, then it seems like I need to use the Multi Statement Table-Value Function. I'm still working on it. I was able to get the "Insert Exec" way to work. I added that below. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Multi statement table valued functions can work fine. Keep in mind that you want to limit its results to 1000 rows then because table valued function returns a table variable which comes wiry this limitation.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. My HUGE query returns 8000 rows. My HUGE query is also a Select statement. I received a message saying "Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client." That's fine. I got the result I needed and learned some new stuff about SQL Server. Thanks again.

Comment: It could be possible to transform your query into something that fits within online table valued functions. Do you mind updating your question with it?

Comment: I just added my pseudocode for the inline table valued function. I added it to the original question.

Comment: The function worked perfectly. There were no issues with performance, like I had with Insert-Exec. It also helped with readability.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `INSERT EXEC` statement.

```
Alter Procedure spMyStoredProc
Begin
    --Value of 1 for each param means I want to execute the query
    @sqlQueryA Bit = 0,
    @sqlQueryB Bit = 0,
    @sqlQueryC Bit = 0

    Insert Into #MyTempTable
    Exec spHugeQuery --here you execute the stored proc that selects from huge query 

    If @sqlQueryA = 1 
    Begin    
        Select * From #MyTempTable
    End
    Else If @sqlQueryB = 1
       ... 
    Else If @sqlQueryC = 1
    Begin
        Query something else from #MyTempTable
    End
    Else
        Return
End
```

**Advantage**

This solution is most in line with your original solution and will work well if you need to set variables to be used in the query.

**Disadvantage**

The stored proc `spHugeQuery` needs to return the right number of columns and the right data types that can be inserted into your temp table. If something changes in either your temp table definition or your select statement in the stored proc, you wouldn't know until it fails at run time.

Comment: I wanted to use this solution, but I reverted back to the code I had on my original question. The Insert-Exec worked for some of my queries off the temp table, but other queries performed horribly. The queries using the Like keyword were unusable.

Answer (score 0):

The idea from Evaldas Buinauskas ended up being the answer that worked best for me. It solved the readability problem, local variable problem, and performed well. Note that I moved my HUGE query into an Inline Table Valued Function. You can see it being called in the code below. I am passing my local vars as parameters to the function. The function creates the temp table I needed.

```
Alter Procedure spMyStoredProc
Begin

@SqlAsParam Nvarchar(100),
@otherParam DataType,
…

Declare @localVarA DataType
Set @localVarA = value

Declare @localVarB DataType
Set @localVarB = value  

Select * 
Into #MyTempTable
From dbo.fn_GetHUGEquery(@localVarA, @localVarB)

If @SqlAsParam = 'sqlQueryA'
  Begin    
     Select * From #MyTempTable
  End
Else If @SqlAsParam = 'sqlQueryB'
       ... 
Else If @SqlAsParam = 'sqlQueryC'
  Begin
      Query something else from #MyTempTable
  End
Else
     Return
End
```